# OSX installing numpy via brew for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, homebrew

I can't install numpy for python3 via brew.

I type:

```
brew install numpy --with-python3
```

then it's OK for python2

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

but still not found for python3

```
Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 15 2014, 23:02:41) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
>>>
```

How to make it work for python3 ?

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to install it is via:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

Obviously, you need to install python3 and pip first. I tested and works without any problem.

Comment: thanks, I know pip3 works just fine. Maybe I wasn't precise, I need to install from brew. It's about specific version and other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the Homebrew is that it sees only the system's python and the one it installed itself. So you have to first install python3 via brew and then use the --with-python3 option.